# How to make ion-icon have save behaviour as ion-select?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, frontend

I have this code:

```
<ion-col  class="settings ion-text-end">
            <ion-icon name="pricetags-outline" size="small" (click)="headerService.openSelect()"></ion-icon>
            <ion-select style="display: none;" interface="popover" fill="none" *ngIf="!headerService.noPShops && headerService.showSearch() && headerService.selectVisible"
              (ionFocus)="headerService.updateShops()" [(ngModel)]="headerService.selectedPShop"
              id="selectPhysical">
              <ion-select-option *ngFor="let shop of headerService.pshops" [value]="shop.url">{{shop.name}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let shop of headerService.pshops" [value]="shop.url">{{shop.name}}</ion-select-option>
            <ion-icon (click)="headerService.changeMenu()" name="settings-sharp" size="small" title="Configuración"></ion-icon>
          </ion-col>
```

I need to make the ion-icon act like the ion-select. Or at least, make the ion-select have the same design as the ion-icon.

Tried to make the ion-select display none, but... Well, the ion-select-options didn't appear.

Any way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a similar behavior as `ion-select` with an `ion-icon`, you can use `ion-popover` to display the options when the icon is clicked. Here's how you can do it:

1. Create a popover component that will display the options:

popover-component.ts:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-popover',
  template: `
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let shop of pshops" (click)="selectShop(shop.url)">
        {{ shop.name }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  `,
})
export class PopoverComponent {
  @Input() pshops: any[];

  selectShop(shopUrl: string) {
    // Implement the logic to handle the selected shop here
    console.log(shopUrl);
  }
}
```

2. Add the popover component to your app module:

app.module.ts:

```js
import { PopoverComponent } from './popover-component';

@NgModule({
  // ... other imports and declarations
  declarations: [PopoverComponent],
  entryComponents: [PopoverComponent], // Add this line
})
export class AppModule {}
```

3. In your main component, open the popover when the icon is clicked:

main-component.ts:

```js
import { PopoverController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { PopoverComponent } from './popover-component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  template: `
    <!-- Your other template code -->

    <ion-col class="settings ion-text-end">
      <ion-icon name="pricetags-outline" size="small" (click)="openPopover($event)"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon (click)="headerService.changeMenu()" name="settings-sharp" size="small" title="Configuración"></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
  `,
})
export class MainComponent {
  constructor(private popoverController: PopoverController) {}

  async openPopover(event: Event) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverComponent,
      event,
      translucent: true,
      componentProps: {
        pshops: headerService.pshops,
      },
    });
    await popover.present();
  }
}
```

With this setup, when the `ion-icon` is clicked, a popover will be displayed with the options from the `ion-select`. When the user selects an option from the popover, the `selectShop()` method in the `PopoverComponent` will be called, and you can implement the logic to handle the selected shop there.